# Xamarin Forms Switch Control Not Working Reliably on Android Phone

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, switch-statement

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to deploy to a Kyocera E6715 Phone, Android Version 4.4.2

I have used the code found in [Xamarin Forms Switch C# Example](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Switch) to deploy to my E6715 and the switch generated by this "simple code" does not always respond to a finger swipe. Sometimes it does, and sometimes it does not, which is very puzzling.

I tried this same code in the Visual Studio Emulator and it works every time (using the mouse instead of my finger).

Has anyone else had problems with the Xamarin Forms Switch control on Android, or know of a Xamarin Forms solution?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Your device issue? Try another device. And you can use `public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)` call back function to check if your device can detect the touch event.

Comment: Mike - Thanks for the reply but I just tried the same code on another phone : Kyocera E6830, Android Version 6.0.1, and I have the same issue.

Comment: I have tested in my nexus 6 device it works fine. Make sure your finger must touch in the switch round button.

Comment: @Scott, does it also happen on emulators? If it seems device specific, try the latest Forms stable & pre-release packages, then [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?classification=__all) should the issue persist. See [When and how should I file a bug report?](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/howto-file-bug/). A minimized runnable test project, steps to reproduce, and [full version information](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/) would be a great start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, it works perfectly on Visual Studio 2015 Emulators. The Switch just fails to work on any android device that I own (reliably) - I only have 2 of them. My "solution", if you call it that, is to not use the Switch control in my Xamarin Forms projects. All other xamarin forms controls respond normally to finger swipes (such as a Picker). As @Mike Ma says, it might be that my finger is not always contacting the switch round button, and this seems like something that I will just have to accept if using Xamarin Forms instead of Device Dependent coding.

Comment: In the Forms source code, the switch control is the native control, so it’s possible that the behavior comes down to the touch responsiveness of those particular devices, unfortunately. You could try a UITest to try to determine if the device has trouble getting touch input in some circumstances. Another potential approach would be to use AppCompat if you aren’t already (or test without if you are)—maybe the AppCompat switch widget will behave differently for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the Xamarin Switch control works unreliably on the Kyocera E6715 and Kyocera E6830. Meaning, when a user swipes, the switch does not always change state.

Other users have (@Mike Ma confirmed) that the switch control works on some other devices (Nexus 6 works).